# How to inject Optional<Resource> only if file exists?

Tags: java, spring

Can I tell spring to inject the resource only if the resource file really exists? Because for the following, `res.isPresent()` is always true if the property `my.path.to.file` was defined. But I only want it to be true if the resource behind really exists.

```
@Value("${my.path.to.file}")
private Optional<Resource> res;
```

Comment: A thought: if you put this into IntelliJ, you'll get a warning. *Optional was designed to provide a limited mechanism for library method return types where there needed to be a clear way to represent "no result". Using a field with type java.util.Optional is also problematic if the class needs to be Serializable, which java.util.Optional is not.* : think if using optional here is really necessary or could be avoided :)

Comment: You can inject value into separate String` property and in `PostConstruct` check that file exists and init your `res` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically there are two options depending on what type of autowiring can use.
If you can use (or easily change your code to use) constructor autowiring then you could do the following:

```
@Autowired
public YourBean(@Value("${my.path.to.file}") String path) {
  if (resourceExists) { //your check here
    res = Optional.of(yourExistingResource);
  } else {
    res = Optional.empty();
  }
}
```

Second option is to use `@PostConstruct` annotation

```
@Value("${my.path.to.file}")
private String resourceName;
private Optional<Resoucre> res;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
  //check that resource exists. At this time all dependencies are already injected.
  if (exists) {
    //init yourResoucre if it is not initialized earlier
    res = Optional.of(yourResource);
  } else {
    res = Optional.empty();
  }
}
```

I would prefer constructor injection